How to get the total count of groups using Spring Boot JPA with pagination?
I'm currently implementing a grouping feature.
In the frontend, there is a grid that displays the "Topic" entity. The frontend sends the column (field) to be used for grouping, the number of rows needed, and some filters.
In this case, the frontend wants to group by the column "Room," which is a reference to an entity on "Topic."
To ensure pagination works properly, I need to return the total number of groups that would exist if no pagination was applied. Currently, I achieve this with two separate queries, but I don't think this is the optimal solution.
Here is the (slightly simplified) main query. It's implemented in a custom repository
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Tuple> mainQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
final Root<Topic> groupRoot = mainQuery.from(Topic.class);

var groupJoin = groupRoot.join(Topic_.room, JoinType.LEFT);

mainQuery.multiselect(groupJoin);
mainQuery.groupBy(groupJoin);

//passed in
Specification<Topic> combinedSpecification = filterSpec.and(keysSpec);
Predicate mainPredicate = combinedSpecification.toPredicate(groupRoot, mainQuery, criteriaBuilder);
mainQuery.where(mainPredicate);

var startAndSize = getStartAndSize(paginationParameter);
final List<Tuple> mainQueryResult = em.createQuery(mainQuery)
            .setFirstResult(startAndSize.getFirst()) //<- paginated
            .setMaxResults(startAndSize.getSecond()) //<- paginated
            .getResultList();



For the count query, I build almost the same query but without the setFirstResult/setMaxResults, and then count them. For each column, I have two almost identical queries. Is there a way to get the count of the groups without an extra query?
I tried to count the groups with sepereate queries that look like this.
final CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
final Root<Topic> countRoot = countQuery.from(Topic.class);
var countJoin = countRoot.join(Topic_.room, JoinType.LEFT);

Specification<Topic> combinedSpecification = filterSpec.and(keysSpec);
Predicate countPredicate = combinedSpecification.toPredicate(countRoot, countQuery, criteriaBuilder);

countQuery.where(countPredicate);
countQuery.groupBy(countJoin);
countQuery.multiselect(criteriaBuilder.count(countJoin));
int totalCount = em.createQuery(countQuery).getResultList().size();


which seems like a pretty stupid solution.

I you use Hibernate (at least 6.5.3), you can use HibernateCriteriaBuilder instead of CriteriaBuilder. And to get count, you can do: TypedQuery countQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq.createCountQuery()); Long totalElements = countQuery.getSingleResult();

and use JpaCriteriaQuery instead of CriteriaQuery. This interface has method createCountQuery()

you can use a subquery to calculate the distinct group count and then return the paginated data. In this way, you can achieve both the count and the grouped results in one go.
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Tuple> mainQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
final Root<Topic> groupRoot = mainQuery.from(Topic.class);
var groupJoin = groupRoot.join(Topic_.room, JoinType.LEFT);

mainQuery.multiselect(groupJoin);
mainQuery.groupBy(groupJoin);

Specification<Topic> combinedSpecification = filterSpec.and(keysSpec);
Predicate mainPredicate = combinedSpecification.toPredicate(groupRoot, mainQuery, criteriaBuilder);
mainQuery.where(mainPredicate);

final Subquery<Long> groupCountQuery = mainQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Topic> groupCountRoot = groupCountQuery.from(Topic.class);
var groupCountJoin = groupCountRoot.join(Topic_.room, JoinType.LEFT);
groupCountQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(groupCountJoin)).where(mainPredicate);

var startAndSize = getStartAndSize(paginationParameter);
final List<Tuple> mainQueryResult = em.createQuery(mainQuery)
    .setFirstResult(startAndSize.getFirst())
    .setMaxResults(startAndSize.getSecond())
    .getResultList();

long totalGroupCount = em.createQuery(groupCountQuery).getSingleResult();

Query query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT new package.CountData((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r) FROM Topic t LEFT JOIN t.room r WHERE <conditions>), t) " +
    "FROM Topic t LEFT JOIN t.room r WHERE <conditions> GROUP BY r");


Thanks you for the answer.
But i cant use this line: long totalGroupCount = em.createQuery(groupCountQuery).getSingleResult()
a subquery cant be used like a normal query
